# constructing URL overcoming ajax

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to extract some table in iframe,
so I got the src URL from it to get to the URL directly.

Using chrome inspection, I found query string rules to construct the 
URL of my target table. 
But interestingly, I found whenever I tried getting a result table from this constructed URL, I failed to retrieve the table, with bs4 yielding me an empty result. And when I delete the word "ajax" from the URL, it retrieves some funny distorted table, with some information missing. 
I want to avoid using Selenium as much as I can.

The following link is the src URL I extracted from iframe of an original web page.
And the table is shown by clicking the element with attribute name "cns_Tab21"
http://bitly.kr/sBKDIK
Thank you for reading this post!

Comment: There is lots of table available on webpage.Which table you would like to fetch?

Comment: @KunduK thanks ; it's from clicking the item of the tag with an id = cns_Tab21 I guess. Sorry if it's wrong; my chrome browser is currently acting abnormally for no reason (shutting down its inspection menu) so I can't check it properly now.

Answer (score 0):

I have few suggestions for this .

1. Check the data availability in source code page
2. Try to identify the actual source of the data using inspect > network (Also you can use this **charlesproxy** for debugging)
3. Download HAR file and check for the origin source

This might help you to sort out this. 90% sites doesn't require selenium

Comment: Thank you for your comment For the suggestion 1 ane 2, When I use insepect> network and double click on the file loaded if I click the table toggle tab, it shows me the table query data well. And this is what I built my URL for. I will try checking HAR soon.